# Ubuntu 13.04 three-finger window moving not working anymore

Tags: 13.04, touchpad, multi-touch

I juste upgraded to **Ubuntu 13.04** on my Samsung New Series 9 (**NP900X4C-A01FR**).

Before, in **12.10**, I could **move/minimize/maximize** the windows, using 3 fingers. These 3 functions doesn't work anymore.

How to recover these ?

And here is what works :

- **2 fingers** : *scrolling*
- **3 fingers** : *2 tap to display the windows switcher*
- **4 fingers** : *1 tap to launch the dash*, *swipe gesture to show/hide the launcher*

Thanks.

Comment: There is also four finger swipe left and right to reveal/hide the Unity bar (if you have it auto-hide). But all the useful gestures seem to have broken. :'-(

In any case, we're not alone: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1172172

Comment: you're right, I forgot about this one cause i've never really used it :) I marked as affected by this bug on launchpad, thx. btw I think -as this is a confirmed bug- that you can anwser my question with you comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a ticket opened for this bug which can be tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1172172

I miss my gestures too. :-(

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this has been removed 'by design'. The bug mentioned by @Anthony has been set to "Won't Fix".

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1172172/comments/16

It's bullshit, really.