# updated to ubuntu 13.04, 3 finger gestures are gone

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, usability

Before Gnome3, Ubuntu emulated middle click with 3 fingers tap on the touchpad.

After Gnome3, it was used to drag windows (and maximize/restore). I missed the very useful middle click gesture, but at least I had something in return.

Now I just upgraded to 13.04, and I have neither.

OK, just noticed, now that I have more than one window open, it's the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (once). So I can just alternate between two windows.

Is there any way to have either of the old behaviors? Ideally the middle click simulation? I consider that one to be the ultimate feature for the 3 finger touchpad gesture, as most laptops only have two physical buttons.

thank you

Comment: duplicate question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/288225/ubuntu-13-04-three-finger-window-moving-not-working-anymore

Comment: @Sulliwane agreed. although i'd still love the middle click emulation better, i guess for the title i should agree that this is a duplicate. Edit: how do I close it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dkms I could load the drivers, but still not working on my samsung notebook

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo wget http://www.ouam.fr/~madko/ubuntu/elantech/psmouse-elantech-v7.tar.bz2
sudo tar jxvf psmouse-elantech-v7.tar.bz2
sudo dkms add -m psmouse -v elantech-v7
sudo dkms build -m psmouse -v elantech-v7
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-v7
```

and then you restart your computer and run

```
xinput --list
```

my outuput was :

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]    
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Try that and see if it works, still don't fully working for me

Comment: thanks for the input. accepting older open questions that are not relevant anymore. (though things are still broken)