# Ubuntu 14.04 gnome touchpad gestures

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, touchegg

I want to extend the touchpad gestures of the system, I've ran into [touchegg](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/) but in my case it did not work. I've read its not working on ubuntu 14.04 gnome environment.

Any help is appreciated. I want to approach OS X like gestures. I am using a Lenovo U330p laptop.

Comment: What gestures do you want? Natural scroll, swipe, pinch zoom... Please add some more information to your question.

Comment: I want **drag** windows mainly with **three fingers**. All others are not so important. Natural scroll is already an option in Mouse & Touchpad settings, but im not a big fan of it. I always swipe workspaces with the keyboard on osx, and it can be done on the same way on ubuntu. `ctrl + alt + arrows`

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/288225/ubuntu-13-04-three-finger-window-moving-not-working-anymore) question...